# Retrieve name ID from php json file

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this php file for country/state/town list using json method.

**PHP file:**

```
sleep(1);

$stateID = $_GET['stateID'];
$countyID = $_GET['countyID'];
$townID = $_GET['townID'];
$html = $_GET['html'];

$states = array();
$states['MA'] = "Massachusetts";
$states['VT'] = "Vermont";
$states['SC'] = "South Carolina";


$counties = array();
$counties['MA']['BARN'] = 'Barnstable';
$counties['MA']['PLYM'] = 'Plymouth';
$counties['VT']['CHIT'] = 'Chittenden';
$counties['SC']['ANDE'] = 'Anderson';

$towns = array();
$towns['MA']['BARN']['CHA'] = "Chatham";
$towns['MA']['BARN']['DEN'] = "Dennis";
$towns['MA']['BARN']['YAR'] = "Yarmouth";
$towns['MA']['PLYM']['BRI'] = "Bridgewater";
$towns['MA']['PLYM']['MAR'] = "Marshfield";
$towns['MA']['PLYM']['WAR'] = "Wareham";
$towns['VT']['CHIT']['BUR'] = "Burlington";
$towns['VT']['CHIT']['ESS'] = "Essex";


if($stateID && !$countyID && !$townID){
    echo json_encode( $counties[$stateID] );
} elseif( $stateID && $countyID && !$townID ) {
    echo json_encode( $towns[$stateID][$countyID] );
} elseif( isset($villages[$stateID][$countyID][$townID]) ) {
    echo json_encode( $villages[$stateID][$countyID][$townID] );
} else {
    echo '{}';
}
```

I retrieve value from MySql database(example:MA for country). 
Now I need to print country/state/town name into select box dropdown like this.

```
    <select id="country" class="validate[required]" name="country">
            <option value="0">Choose ...</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="'.$country['selector'].'">Show Country Name From php File</option>
    </select>
    <select id="state" class="validate[required]" name="state">
        <option value="0">Choose ...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="'.$state['selector'].'">Show state Name From php File</option>
    </select>
    <select id="town" class="validate[required]" name="town">
        <option value="0">Choose ...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="'.$town['selector'].'">Show town Name From php File</option>
    </select>
```

How can I print this?

Comment: `<option selected="selected" value="'.$country['selector'].'">"'.$country['selector'].'"</option>`

Comment: Do you want to populate the boxes server-side, or using AJAX?  The use of JSON (and indeed MySQL) is confusing me.

Comment: print the same values in between the option tags also

Comment: @eggyal:in add page, i put value in MySql database. now in retrieve value form MySql database and need to print name from this file using JSON and jQuery/AJAX.

Comment: If the values are in a database, why do you populate the arrays statically?

Comment: @eggyal: i mixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file that makes the call to the database. The results are, normally, stored in a php array. You can turn this array into Json using json_encode()(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Simply echo this in the php-file.

Now call that script with jQuery. There is a simple jQuery method called getJson(). - Read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

This will bring the MySQL results to you - in Json form - and you could now use JavaScript to loop the results, and display the form accordingly. A simple example would be (I haven't tested this but I hope you get the idea):

```
$.each(data, function() {
     $('#mySelect')
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value",data[row].NameOfColumn)
     .text(value));
     row ++; 
});
```

Note the name of column - that's the name of the key for the value you are looking for. In your case you might want to loop the keys as well - with an outer loop - since the data seems to be presented in such a matter.